# How do I center a table within the main page/part of my site?

Tags: css

I understand how to center within each cell. I also know how to do this on an html page. I am familiar with tweaking the CSS and the nightandday master page (that's what we're using).

I just need a two column table with a width I have set to be centered on the main portion of the site page. I have added `.ms-rteTable-default` but that changes all tables on the site.

Just need the **main section of the page** to do this (not the side nav section or the title bar or ribbon bar, etc)
Can't figure it out.

Comment: use table's id instead of class

Comment: Thanks. Looked at Inspect Element and found this: <table id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte_layoutsTable style="WIDTH: 100%">        Is this correct ID?

Comment: Yes, you can use it, just be aware that if you remove and re-add the content with these auto-generated ids, they will change :)

Comment: Ended up using class and css. Not sure what I was missing before but it works perfectly in IE 11, FFox and Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Using class and css ended up working perfectly